# Sierpinski space is an example of a normal space that is not regular

Tags: general-topology, logic, proof-verification, proof-writing, separation-axioms

On Wikipedia there is a claim:  Sierpinski space is an example of a normal space that is not regular. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_space

I can see why it is not regular. I think the proof for by it is not normal requires "proof by vacuous truth" type of argument which I am not good at. Can someone check if this is legit.

> Let $(S, \tau) = (\{0,1\}, \{\{\varnothing\}, \{1\}, \{0,1\}\})$ be the Sierpinski
>   space. Since the only non-trivial closed set is $\{0\}$, and it is not
>   disjoint from $\{\varnothing\}$ or $\{0,1\}$, therefore we fail to
>   satisfy the condition required for normality, so  $(S,\tau)$  is by default normal.

Is there some way to improve this argument? Thanks

By the way isn't $T_4$ = $T_1$ and $normal$ $\implies$ $T_3$ = $T_1$ and $regular$? So why doesn't being normal imply regular?

Comment: Your "by the way" at the end is entirely unclear. I can't make heads or tails of it.

Comment: Some authors (e.g. Engelking : General Topology) especially in older books, define a normal pace to be $T_1$ and $T_4$ and many of them include the $T_1$ property in the def'n of $T_4$.  Engelking calls a space which is not necesarily $T_1$ in which disjoint closed sets are completely separated a pseudo-normal space.  This is now considered to an old-fashioned style.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The argument is basically correct, but you’ve given the topology incorrectly: the first open set should be $\varnothing$, not $\{\varnothing\}$. Also, $\{0\}$ *is* disjoint from the closed set $\varnothing$; the reason that this doesn’t matter is that $X$ and $\varnothing$ are disjoint open nbhds of $A$ and $\varnothing$ for any $A\subseteq X$. Thus, normality is a non-trivial requirement only on disjoint *non-empty* closed sets.

$T_4$ does imply $T_3$. Suppose that $X$ is $T_4$, $x\in X$, and $F$ is a closed subset of $X$ not containing $x$. Since $X$ is $T_4$ and hence $T_1$, $\{x\}$ is closed. Thus, we can use normality to get disjoint open nbhds of $\{x\}$ and $F$, which are of course also disjoint open nbhds of $x$ and $F$.

Normality without the $T_1$ property, however, does not imply regularity, as this example shows.

Comment: Oh I thought $\{0\}$ was not disjoint from $\varnothing$ since $\varnothing \subset A$ for an set $A$? I always thought normality directly implied regularity...:(

Comment: @Unicorn-Shark Invasion: $X$ and $Y$ are disjoint if $X\cap Y=\varnothing$. So ***every*** set is disjoint from $\varnothing$.

Comment: @Unicorn-SharkInvasion: Sets $A$ and $B$ are disjoint if and only if $A\cap B=\varnothing$; $\{0\}\cap\varnothing=\varnothing$, so $\{0\}$ and $\varnothing$ are disjoint. (Indeed, $\varnothing$ is disjoint from *every* set!)

Comment: @AsafKaragila Oops!

Comment: I've never seen normality stated as a requirement on only disjoint non-empty closed sets.  It's just that it's trivial if one of the sets is empty: you can separate any closed set from the empty set using the open sets $X$ and $\emptyset$.

Comment: @Eric: Six of one, half a dozen of the other. I’ve actually seen both, but it probably wasn’t a good idea to choose the uncommon one, and it was certainly a bad idea to imply that the other doesn’t work. I’ll change it.

Comment: Brian, what about "the successor of five" and "three pairs"? :-)

Comment: @Asaf: Boring. How about ‘the first perfect number’, or ‘the factorial of the first odd prime’?

Comment: The seventh part of the second successor of the eight multiple of the third prime.